# Xamarin Forms fade to hidden?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my current app, I have a bunch of buttons which can hide or show their corresponding stackLayout. 
First, i tried using IsVisble property, but this causes a flash,
now im at using LayoutTo() which also flashes?

My code is as below:

```
async void btnStrike_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var layout = this.FindByName<StackLayout>("stkStrikeInfo");
            var rect = new Rectangle(layout.X, layout.Y, layout.Width, layout.Height - layout.Height);
            await layout.LayoutTo(rect, 2500, Easing.Linear);
        }
```

Id like to animate the height!

Edit:

I found the following piece of code, which removes the Stacklayout from the page. 
The issue now is that the view isnt updating?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you'll have better luck with just a default animation that reduces the height of the layout you want to hide to zero.

```
void btnStrike_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // get reference to the layout to animate
    var layout = this.FindByName<StackLayout>("stkStrikeInfo");

    // setup information for animation
    Action<double> callback = input => { layout.HeightRequest = input; }; // update the height of the layout with this callback
    double startingHeight = layout.Height; // the layout's height when we begin animation
    double endingHeight = 0; // final desired height of the layout
    uint rate = 16; // pace at which aniation proceeds
    uint length = 1000; // one second animation
    Easing easing = Easing.CubicOut; // There are a couple easing types, just tried this one for effect

    // now start animation with all the setup information
    layout.Animate("invis", callback, startingHeight, endingHeight, rate, length, easing);
}
```

If the layout is already hidden and you want to show it, you would replace

```
double startingHeight = layout.Height;
double endingHeight = 0;
```

with

```
double startingHeight = 0;
double endingHeight = 55;
```

The 55 is just an arbitrary height, if you want it to go back to the height from before, you would save the previous height to a variable before you hide it and use that saved height instead of 55.

Comment: Hello, It gives an error for the callback, "Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicity typed variable"

Comment: Cannot convert from System.Action to Xamarin.Forms.Animation

Comment: It was trying to use the wrong overload of Animate, try again with the explicit variable types in the edit.

Comment: How would I go about doing the opposite? Is it switching the start and end?

Comment: Added additional information about unhiding. See edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108647/discussion-between-abrar-ali-and-william-corncob-decker).

Comment: Helpful note for others implementing this solution: make sure the parent view has "IsClippedToBounds" set to True, otherwise you'll see some strange behavior where contents appear to extend below the new height of the parent view.