# Dropdown menu in Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, renderer

I have a tabbedpage design like so,[image: The tabbed page]

The tabbedpage is already setup, but I can't figure out anyway to achieve the dropdown menu and add an extra button (the filter button in the Image) to the tabbar. A custom renderer for the tabbedpage might work but I'd prefer that as a last resort, please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with an `AbsoluteLayout` and some height calculating. No custom renderer needed.

Put everything in your `TabbedPage.Content` in an `AbsoluteLayout` and then to `StackLayout` (or other `Layout` you are using). Then add a `Frame` (i'm using `Frame`, but you can use other `View`).

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="absoluteLayout">
     <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
         //other layouts and elements
     </StackLayout>
     <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,A" IsVisible="False">
         //your checkboxes and labels
     </Frame>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

In the Frame property `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,A"` I wrote A, but you have to write a number there:

- A = the height of your DropDown Menu

If you don't know the height at the initializing of the XAML, you can set it in code too:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(frame, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, height)); // X,Y,Width,Height
```

Explanation and more about Flags is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout). It's quite easy to understand, but if you have trouble, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8S6R_ZKVhU) helped me.

Now is your DropDown ready. When you want it to show, just set the visibility.

```
frame.IsVisisble = true;
```

**Tip-1** : You can even animate it to go up and down with using Animations. For example, [this peace of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501796/3495516) will do it.

**Tip-2** : If you add a `GestureRecognizers` to your `StackLayout`, the user can click around the DropDown and it will hide.

*XAML:*

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
     <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="StackLayout_Tapped"/>
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

*CODE:*

```
if (frame.IsVisisble)
{
    frame.IsVisisble = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Martinedo, i'll start implementing with your example and see where I end up. But, I have one issues before the dropdown itself, and I failed to point that out. The filter button in the Tabbar (from the image), I can't find a way to a put an extra button in a tabbar, except adding a page and disabling that page.

Comment: Well, this is not possible without a custom renderer. Android can do it, but I don't think that iOS can. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511454/3495516 . I would recommend you to find an other approach to place the filter button,

Comment: Ok, I have decided to put leave it as a toolbar item. Will get back here once I implement it. if it works out fine with your code i'll accept the answer.

Comment: Hi, Martinedo. After thinking things through, I've decided to go with renderers for this, so that I have more control. I'll create a custom view and find native solutions on Android and IOS to achieve my goal. Then I'll post the answer.

Comment: could you then please post your solution? I have to deal with similar problem. Achieved it with AbsoluteLayout, but its not bad to see it with a custom renderer